# Logical operations on arrays in Julia

Tags: python, boolean, logic, julia

I have two nxm matrices of 1's and 0's (call them A and B). I want to convert them to Boolean variables and then apply "and" and "or" operations to them. In python, this is easy:

```
A = np.array(A, dtype=bool)
B = np.array(B, dtype=bool)
    
A | B 
A & B
```

However, I want to do the same thing in Julia, and I am having some issues. I first convert to Boolean via

```
A = convert(Array{Bool}, A)
B = convert(Array{Bool},B)
```

But then I do A&&B, I get

```
TypeError: non-boolean (Array{Bool,2}) used in boolean context
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We first create matrices that store `0`-`1` values:

```
julia> using Random

julia> Random.seed!(1234);

julia> A = rand([0, 1], 3, 4)
3×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 0  0  1  1
 0  1  1  0
 1  0  1  0

julia> B = rand([0, 1], 3, 4)
3×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  1  1  0
 0  1  1  1
 0  1  1  1
```

Then broadcast using `.` the  `Bool` constructor to get boolean matrices:

```
julia> A_bool = Bool.(A)
3×4 BitArray{2}:
 0  0  1  1
 0  1  1  0
 1  0  1  0

julia> B_bool = Bool.(B)
3×4 BitArray{2}:
 1  1  1  0
 0  1  1  1
 0  1  1  1
```

Similarly use the `.` broadcasting on `&` and `|` operators to get what you want:

```
julia> A_bool .| B_bool
3×4 BitArray{2}:
 1  1  1  1
 0  1  1  1
 1  1  1  1

julia> A_bool .& B_bool
3×4 BitArray{2}:
 0  0  1  0
 0  1  1  0
 0  0  1  0
```

Note that in this particular case using `|` and `&` on the original matrices would get an equivalent result (but the matrices would contain `0`-`1` integers):

```
julia> A .| B
3×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  1  1  1
 0  1  1  1
 1  1  1  1

julia> A .& B
3×4 Array{Int64,2}:
 0  0  1  0
 0  1  1  0
 0  0  1  0
```

Comment: Note that you can get `Bool` matrices by doing `rand(Bool, 3, 4)` - in that case no conversion would be required.

Comment: Yes, but then you get a `Array{Bool, 2}` instead of a `BitArray{2}`, and this is not as efficiently stored in memory AFAIK.

Comment: `Bool.(A)` creates a BitArray. Alternatively, to create a matrix of `Bool`s, use `Matrix{Bool}(A)` or `convert(Matrix{Bool}, A)`.

Comment: Yes - this is what Jushuah did, but I thought of showing `Bool.` option in the answer as it is less typing :).